# Filtering specific table columns based on chosen value from select box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I have a select dropdown using the jquery "chosen" that is connected to a sql DB and a table also connected to the same DB. I want to filter the table based on the selected value of the select dropdown. I'm accomplishing the filtering of the table, but the problem is that it is filtering values based on every cell in every column. I want it to just filter based on just the first 2 columns of the table. For example, I have a ProjectID and ProjectName in the dropdown and I want to only filter the table based on those values. Say I have a projectID of 60 and there's a 60 in another cell in the table(say "hours" column) with a projectID of 59, right now it will return that row with ProjectID of 59. Any pointers are very appreciated. Here's my script:

```
    //page load
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".chosen").chosen({         
            no_results_text: "Nothing found!"              
        });       

        displaygrid();

    });

    //functions
    function displaygrid() {
        $('#chosenproj').change(function () {
            var selection = $(this).val();
            $('tbl1')[selection ? 'show' : 'hide']();
            if (selection) {  // iterate only if `selection` is not empty
                $.each($('#tbl1 tbody tr'), function (index, item) {
                    $(item)[$(item).is(':contains(' + selection + ')') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
                });
            }
        });
    };

</script>
```

Here's my html markup:

```
      <div>          
        <select id="chosenproj" class="chosen" runat="server"  
          datatextfield="ProjectFull" datavaluefield="ProjectID" 
         style="width:350px;">               
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table id="tbl1" class="tblsorter">    
     <thead>                   
            <tr>                   
                <th>ProjectID</th>                    
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>TaskDescription</th>
                <th>TaskDueDate</th>
                <th>StatusDescription</th>
                <th>EstimatedHours</th>
                <th>SprintDateRange</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>   
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptTasks" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("ProjectID") %></td>                        
                    <td><%# Eval("ProjectName") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("TaskDescription") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("TaskDueDate", "{0:d}") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("StatusDescription") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("EstimatedHours") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("SprintDateRange") %></td>                   
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
     </table>
         </div>
```

C# page code behind that link to my DBConnection and classes to source the ddl and table:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        chosenproj.DataSource = ProjectModel.GetProjectList();
        chosenproj.DataBind();
        rptTasks.DataSource = ProjectModel.TaskList();
        rptTasks.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: where is your `sql DB` query?

Comment: I'm wanting to do client-side filtering, not server-side. It's a relatively small dataset, so we pull everything at once